# Capture a data element from a column

Tags: sql-server

I need some SQL Server expertise capturing a data element from a column. Please consider the strings below.

```
"How to capture 04340-TEST-0030-dd-01 data from a string"
"How to capture some data 8383228-TEST-0030-q1-010123 data from a string in MS SQL"
"How to capture something 043140-TEST-0030-z9-0111 data from a string in SQL Server 2022"
```

I would like to extract the following from this.

```
04340-TEST-0030-dd-01
8383228-TEST-0030-q1-010123
043140-TEST-0030-z9-0111
```

The only piece that is consistent is the word TEST. The characters to the left and right of it are not uniform.

Basically, once the TEST part is located, I need to capture everything to the right until a space and everything to the left until a space.

I've attempted using substring and charindex. However, I couldn't figure out how to capture the data needed.

Comment: Post what you have tried and the ONE issue you are challenged with in that code.

Comment: I played around using substring and charindex. Never had anything that would produce the result needed. Not sure how to search to the left and right for the next space.

Comment: I'd suggest you pull the data out into a language with regular expressions, and shred the values there.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using string_split

```
Select *
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply string_split(SomeCol,' ') B
 Where B.value like '%-%-%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution based on *tokenization* via SQL Server's XML and XQuery functionality.

For example, the first row will be tokenized as follows:

```
<root>
  <r>How</r>
  <r>to</r>
  <r>capture</r>
  <r>04340-TEST-0030-dd-01</r>
  <r>data</r>
  <r>from</r>
  <r>a</r>
  <r>string</r>
</root>
```

After that XPath predicate `[contains(.,"-TEST-")]` gets us what is needed.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(1024));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('How to capture 04340-TEST-0030-dd-01 data from a string'),
('How to capture some data 8383228-TEST-0030-q1-010123 data from a string in MS SQL'),
('How to capture something 043140-TEST-0030-z9-0111 data from a string in SQL Server 2022');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

SELECT *
    , c.value('(/root/r/text()[contains(.,"-TEST-")])[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
    REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

| id | tokens | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | How to capture 04340-TEST-0030-dd-01 data from a string | 04340-TEST-0030-dd-01 |
| 2 | How to capture some data 8383228-TEST-0030-q1-010123 data from a string in MS SQL | 8383228-TEST-0030-q1-010123 |
| 3 | How to capture something 043140-TEST-0030-z9-0111 data from a string in SQL Server 2022 | 043140-TEST-0030-z9-0111 |